# Accessing R packages from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, r, iis, r.net

I have an asp.net app where I am using R.NET. Everything works fine until I load a package using

```
library()
```

The web app of course runs in IIS and I get this error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'lattice'".

Though it loads and works perfectly fine in Rstudio.

Its some problem of R.NET not working with IIS.

I have been searching around and it has been marked as a Known Issue on https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/. I was wondering if any one has found a workaround for this error.

I went through https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/issues/9 but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation page http://rdotnet.github.io/rdotnet/ts_asp_dot_net/ describes a problem very similar to yours. Can you read it, and its companion page http://rdotnet.github.io/rdotnet/tut_asp_dot_net/, and report here if this solves your issue? (for future reference by other readers)

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. All I had to do was to add the path "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64" to my System variables.

Comment: Still not working for me. If I type engine.Evaluate(".libPaths()").AsCharacter() it returns the library folder that my library is in. Any idea why it still won't load?

Comment: @MIKE...If you have not yet solved your issue - when you add a path to env variables so it broadcasts a WM_SETTINGSCHANGE message to all top-level windows and if you want to use that path value so you have to restart your application first in order for it to get the new path value.