# R IIS Deployment Issue

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I am facing deployment issues in IIS
Getting Error

> Error in library(RODBC) : there is no package called 'RODBC' same with
>   other packages also.

Tried changing path in Environment variables also but nothing works for me
But in VS2015 its working fine

Thanks

Comment: When there isn't a package, you should try to install it. `install.packages('RODBC')`

Comment: Yes its already installed , In Visual Studio its working fine

Answer (score 0):

The webpage [R.net for users 1.6](http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/ts_asp_dot_net/) describes a problem with the same package as yours. Note that if R packages are installed in an external folder to the original R installation, it might cause further problems. If that solution does not work try to reinstall these packages, or R altogether, avoiding that the packages get installed to an external folder. Also note that a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623923/accessing-r-packages-from-asp-net) has already been asked although maybe referring to a different problem